# Pivoting single rows into rows with their combined values

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, pivot-table, spread

I would like to transform the column *word* into another column, but with the **original rows combined together, separed by _.**

- Original:

```
> head(df, 10)
# A tibble: 10 x 1
   word    
   <chr>   
 1 Jason   
 2 Oscar   
 3 Maleeka 
 4 Janet   
 5 Gabriel 
 6 Raheema 
 7 Bryce   
 8 Nasreen 
 9 Hishaam 
10 Thadduse
```

- desired output:

```
word 
Jason_Oscar_Maleeka_Janet_Gabriel_Raheema_Bryce_Nasreen_Hishaam_Thadduse
.
.
.
```

**Question**

*1* How do I pivot `word` so that each new row contains 10 words per row separated by "_" ? (Tidyverse and stringr approaches would be much appreciated - thanks!)

- Data:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(word = c("Jason", "Oscar", "Maleeka", "Janet", 
"Gabriel", "Raheema", "Bryce", "Nasreen", "Hishaam", "Thadduse", 
"Marcos", "Daijah", "Chassity", "Carlito", "Chidiebere", "Matthew", 
"Maureene", "Jillian", "Markus", "Aaron", "Ramziyya", "Marquez", 
"Kiera", "Farajallah", "Larisa", "Davier", "Shujaa", "Vincent", 
"Orlando", "Joseph", "Desean", "Chelsea", "Faadil", "Christopher", 
"Aarifa", "Joel", "Matthew", "Jacob", "Aeones", "Matthew", "Jacob", 
"Savannah", "Nadia", "Kaleem", "Tanner", "Sabeeha", "Caitlyn", 
"Taylor", "Sydney", "Devin")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -50L))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are describing isn't a pivot exactly, but you can achieve it as follows:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by((row_number() - 1) %/% 10) %>%
  summarise(word = paste(word, collapse = '_')) %>%
  select(word)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 1
#>   word                                                                           
#>   <chr>                                                                          
#> 1 Jason_Oscar_Maleeka_Janet_Gabriel_Raheema_Bryce_Nasreen_Hishaam_Thadduse       
#> 2 Marcos_Daijah_Chassity_Carlito_Chidiebere_Matthew_Maureene_Jillian_Markus_Aaron
#> 3 Ramziyya_Marquez_Kiera_Farajallah_Larisa_Davier_Shujaa_Vincent_Orlando_Joseph  
#> 4 Desean_Chelsea_Faadil_Christopher_Aarifa_Joel_Matthew_Jacob_Aeones_Matthew     
#> 5 Jacob_Savannah_Nadia_Kaleem_Tanner_Sabeeha_Caitlyn_Taylor_Sydney_Devin
```

Comment: beat me by 52  seconds

Comment: Thank you!! Would you mind explaning the logic behind it?

Comment: @LarissaCury sure. If you take the row numbers and subtract 1, then divide by 10, the first ten values would be 0, 0.1, 0.2, etc up to 0.9. The next ten values would be 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, etc up to 1.9. Note that the integer part of the first 10 numbers is 0, the second ten will be 1, the third 10 will be 2, etc. To divide but only get the integer part we use the modulus operator `%/%`, so `(row_number() -1) %/% 10` gives us this sequence of integers. Now we `group_by` these numbers to group into clumps of 10. Finally, we `paste` the clumps together using `"_"` as a separator.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a base R option with `matrix` approach

```
data.frame(
    word =
        do.call(
            paste,
            c(as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(df), ncol = 10, byrow = TRUE)),
                sep = "_"
            )
        )
)
```

which gives

```
                                                                             word
1        Jason_Oscar_Maleeka_Janet_Gabriel_Raheema_Bryce_Nasreen_Hishaam_Thadduse
2 Marcos_Daijah_Chassity_Carlito_Chidiebere_Matthew_Maureene_Jillian_Markus_Aaron
3   Ramziyya_Marquez_Kiera_Farajallah_Larisa_Davier_Shujaa_Vincent_Orlando_Joseph
4      Desean_Chelsea_Faadil_Christopher_Aarifa_Joel_Matthew_Jacob_Aeones_Matthew
5          Jacob_Savannah_Nadia_Kaleem_Tanner_Sabeeha_Caitlyn_Taylor_Sydney_Devin
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it with `tidyverse`, with real pivoting.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(rn = rep(1:10, nrow(.) %/% 10),
         group = rep(1:5, each = nrow(.) %/% 5)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = word) %>% 
  select(-group) %>% 
  unite(col = word, sep = "_")
```

---

The following modified version is ugly, but is more dynamic (i.e. you only need to change the value to `word_number` without the need to modify the piped operation).

```
word_number <- 10
set_number <- nrow(df) %/% word_number

df %>% 
  mutate(rn = rep(1:word_number, set_number),
         group = rep(1:set_number, each = nrow(.) %/% set_number)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = word) %>% 
  select(-group) %>% 
  unite(col = word, sep = "_")
```

---

### Output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 1
  word                                                                           
  <chr>                                                                          
1 Jason_Oscar_Maleeka_Janet_Gabriel_Raheema_Bryce_Nasreen_Hishaam_Thadduse       
2 Marcos_Daijah_Chassity_Carlito_Chidiebere_Matthew_Maureene_Jillian_Markus_Aaron
3 Ramziyya_Marquez_Kiera_Farajallah_Larisa_Davier_Shujaa_Vincent_Orlando_Joseph  
4 Desean_Chelsea_Faadil_Christopher_Aarifa_Joel_Matthew_Jacob_Aeones_Matthew     
5 Jacob_Savannah_Nadia_Kaleem_Tanner_Sabeeha_Caitlyn_Taylor_Sydney_Devin
```